# Android - PhoneStateListener onCallStateChanged() not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, phone-call, phone-state-listener

I want to implement `onCallStateChanged()` of `PhoneStateListener` and use it's functionality to change audio settings when a call is received.

```
private final class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        Utils.log("CallStateListener");
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Utils.log("Idle");
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Utils.log("OFFHOOK");
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                if(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_OPTION_1, false)){
                    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    int maxStreamValue = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

                    int volumeLevel = prefs.getInt(Constants.PREF_VOLUME_LEVEL, Constants.PREF_VOLUME_LEVEL_DEFAULT);
                    int volume = (int) Math.ceil(maxStreamValue * (volumeLevel / 100.0));

                    if(prefs.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_OPTION_3, false)){
                        Utils.log("Option3 true ringing");
                        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    }
                    Utils.changeNotificationVolume(audioManager, volume);
                    Utils.log("RINGING");
                }
                break;
        }

        callState = state;
    }
}
```

I want to silent just the notifications if Option 1 and Option 3 are on, but a lots of new companies provide only one option for notifications and calls. 
If Option 1 and Option 3 are on, i have set my device to SILENT MODE, but whenever a call is received i want my device to ring. Therefore in `CALL_STATE_RINGING`, i have my code to turn off SILENT MODE and ring the device.

This things only works sometime. After trying a lots of devices i have found out that usually this thing doesn't work on mobiles which lags a lot( are really slow). 
I think this is because if audio settings are changed before mobile starts ringing this work, and if not this doesn't work even if settings are changed. Am i right? Is there any solution to this problem? Is there a way to delay ringing of android device? Or can i do something to make it work every time?

Comment: Facing this issue on SamsungS7. Is anyone able to find the solution for handling Capturing Call State issue?

Comment: Facing issue in android nougat